# Solutions for differential equations in power series form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Can any differential equation be solved trough power series? If not, what are the conditions for convergence?

This question crossed my mind while studying cylindrical guided waves, which use Bessel functions as part of the solution, but if I came across a different equation I wouldn't be able to solve it.

I'm assuming only single-variable functions, since I don't know a lot about multivariate power series, but a generic answer would also be appreciated.

Comment: See  [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_method) called the Frobenius method. Short answer: power series solution are only possible around regular points.

Comment: This is a little more restrictive than what I wanted, since it only works for equations for that form